# Fluent NHibernate with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I am using SQLite for unit test.

```
private ISession _session;
    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        string[] mappingAssemblies = RepositoryTestsHelper.GetMappingAssemblies();
        configuration = NHibernateSession.Init(new SimpleSessionStorage(), mappingAssemblies,
                               new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
                               @"C:\Sharp Architecture\SharpArchitecture_1_6_FullSourceAndTemplates (1)\src\NorthwindSample\tests\Northwind.Tests\Hibernate.cfg.xml");
        _session = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(false, true, false, _session.Connection, null); 
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void TearDown()
    {
        NHibernateSession.CloseAllSessions();
        NHibernateSession.Reset();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings()
    {
        var allClassMetadata = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().GetAllClassMetadata();
        foreach (var entry in allClassMetadata)
        {

            NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria(entry.Value.GetMappedClass(EntityMode.Poco))
                 .SetMaxResults(0).List();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
NHibernate.ADOException : could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.CategoryID as CategoryID0_0_, this_.CategoryName as Category2_0_0_ FROM Categories this_ limit 0 ]
[SQL: SELECT this_.CategoryID as CategoryID0_0_, this_.CategoryName as Category2_0_0_ FROM Categories this_ limit 0]
  ----> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQLite error
no such table: Categories
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List()
at Tests.Northwind.Data.NHibernateMaps.MappingIntegrationTests.CanConfirmDatabaseMatchesMappings() in MappingIntegrationTests.cs: line 50
--SQLiteException
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, ref String strRemain)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
```

**I am using Sharp Architecture.**
Thanks,
Nabin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the class:

```
FluentNHibernate.Testing.SingleConnectionSessionSourceForSQLiteInMemoryTesting
```

It has a BuildSchema() method.